# Variables Naming in Javascript and PHP

Tags: php, javascript

Is it a good idea to use the same naming nomenclature (e.g. camelCase) for both front end (eg. Javascipt) and backend (eg. php) ?

Comment: Use whatever convention preferred for the language you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends.

If you are the only developer I'd say you should use same naming convention on both.

**BUT**

If there is *any* chance that someone else will look at your code you should follow the naming conventions of each language in separation.